# monotouch DialogViewController change order of elements

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am currently using the advanced editing tableview as outlined in Monotouch.Dialog that allows a user to delete as well as edit the label of table elements. Is there a way to enrich the tableview to achieve something similar to the screenshot, i.e. change the ordering?

[image: rearrange order of table elements]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add this two methods to your DialogViewController.Source

```
        public override bool CanMoveRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void MoveRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath sourceIndexPath, NSIndexPath destinationIndexPath)
        {
            tableView.MoveRow(sourceIndexPath,destinationIndexPath);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that works. What would I need to do to commit the changes in the ordering? Currently once I select done is goes back to the initial order.

Comment: in MoveRow() you need to manually make the necessary changes to your datasource so that when it redraws the table they are ordered correctly.

Comment: MonoTouch.Dialog's Sample application (in DemoEditingAdvanced.cs) has been updated to show this feature, ref:  https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/commit/62d5008c50ba3f5479c10a553451a6202af8d382#Sample